# Doxygen @link to a URL doesn't generate the link correctly

Tags: doxygen

I have added this to a class comment:

```
@link http://www.google.com Google @endlink
```

However, when I generate documentation using doxygen, the link text is indeed "Google", but the link is to:

> file:///media/portable/Examples/Doxygen/link/html/classClass1.html

Can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you are using `\link` incorrectly. From the doxygen [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdlink), `\link` is used to refer to objects like a file, class or member and takes a reference to one of these as its first argument. For example, if I wanted to refer to a class method `func` in the class `myClass`, I would use

```
\link myClass::func link text ... \endlink
```

with all of the remaining arguments considered to be text for a link. I think your problem is that you do not pass a valid object as the first argument. I would guess that `classClass1` is the next object in the file where you tried to include the link and this is what the `\link` command is refering to.

**Linking to URLs**

Doxygen will generate URL links automatically, so there is no need to surround the link with `\link` and `\endlink` or any other commands. So remove those and see if that fixes the problem.

To manually specify link text, use the HTML 'a' tag:

```
<a href="linkURL">link text</a>
```

For more information about how doxygen handles automatic linking [see this](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) documentation page.

Comment: When `myClass` is a complicated templated name and that Doxygen autolink breaks, is there a way to "capture" the symbol to link to when documenting `MyClass`? For example adding a `@alias MyClassAlias` in the `myClass` documention block and then be able to write `\link MyClassAlias link text ... \endlink ?

Comment: @WaterFox That sounds like a different question. If you're still looking for an answer, I'd suggest writing this up as a new question.